# UIImageView inside custom UITableViewCell - shows a little distorted image

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiimageview

I'm using `UITableView` with custom cells to create my own selection table.
Each cell has its own `UIImageView`, it's pinned to the right side of cell and there are three constraints on it: right trailing, top and bottom are pinned to these of the superview.
The image I use to show has template render style, there are 3 different sizes for different screen resolutions (16x16,32x32 and 48x48).

Everything works just fine, except one little quirk: the displayed image seems to be shifted up for one or two pixel lines, and these lines are added to the bottom of the image (at least it looks like that).
The view mode is set up as "Center", I tried others, but all modes that do not scale the image (I just want it to show as it is) have the same quirk.

I tried everything I could think of, but no success - the quirk's still here. In the Xcode view hierarchy everything shows just perfect! No quirk!

Has anyone seen anything similar? Are there any secret magic actions to avoid such an effect? My head explodes :(

Here are the screenshots: https://yadi.sk/d/rtTqVqcYfPJB3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have fixed the quirk by one (quite straightforward) step: by adding two blank lines, one line to the top, one line to the bottom of the icon. 
So resulting icon sizes in my case: 16x18, 32x34, 48x50. The quirk is gone totally, but the reason for this weird behavior is still unknown for me.

Answer (score 0):

In storyboard you want to set the UIImageView mode to either aspect fit or aspect fill.

Aspect Fit: fits your image proportionally inside the UIImageView so you might end up with white space

Aspect Fill: fills the UIImageView with you image proportionally but you might have some overflow that cuts off part of your image

You can also do this programmatically:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Comment: Unfortunately, as I already said, all content view modes that do not scale or modify the original image have the same quirk.

Comment: are you using xcassets?

Comment: Yes, all images in the project are in Images.xcassets file. Can this be a problem?

Comment: No that's good. Can you post a screenshot of what the image looks like?